# License Plate Recognition in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, openalpr

I am trying to implement **License Plate Recognition in React Native** for the same I got only single npm package `react-native-openalpr` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-openalpr. I am stuck here because that package is no longer working in android and I only need this functionality for android device.

If anyone having suggestions for the same please share here so we can use such functionality.

Meanwhile I used that package and nothing happening when running in devices and example is crashing.

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue. Have you found an answer to this?

Comment: I am using AWS service for the same none other option.